# prevent ignore empty field in multi value fields

Tags: entities

let suppose I want to create a cast table,
in one field with multi value write down actors and in another write down their roles,
as example

```
 A has "role A"
 B has "role B"
 C          (no role)
 D gas "role D"
```

I fill up field actor with 4 value (it is multi value text field),

```
1)A
2)B
3)C
4)D
```

then in field roles I write down 3 value, the actor "C" has no role

```
1)"role A"
2)"role B"
3)
4)"role D"
```

.

then when I save , I want to show each actor and field in pair, first value of field actor with first value of field role,
but if a actor has not role every thing mixed up

```
 A has "role A"
 B has "role B"
 C has "role D"
 D
```

Is there any way to drupal consider a empty field as filled up field and do not ignore it in save specially between filled up field?

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your Q, but I'd suggest using a field collection (or a custom field) to store both the actor name and their role together, rather than trying to reconcile the two fields as you currently are.

Comment: @Andy I did it with field collection, in field collection have 2 field, actor and role

Comment: Do you have a single-value field collection with multi-value actor and role fields, or a multi-value field collection with single-value actor and role fields? (I'm suggesting the latter, but I guess from your problem you must be using the former?)

Comment: multi value field collection with in each of one , multi actor with multi role :)

Comment: If you have a multi-value field collection with a single-value required actor field, and a single-value optional role field, that should solve your display problems.